# How to Create a new folder in vcenter using rest api

Tags: api, rest, automation, vmware, vcenter

Can anyone help me to provide right API to create a New folder in vcenter

Thanks,
Benji

I can see only get API to list folders in vmware api document, unable to  find any create folder API

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that functionality doesn't yet exist in the vSphere Automation (REST) API. It *can* be done through the vSphere Management (SOAP) API though.  There's a `CreateFolder` method that can be found when interacting with the Folder managed object: [Link to Docs](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/bf660c0a-f060-46e8-a94d-4b5e6ffc77ad/208bc706-e281-49b6-a0ce-b402ec19ef82/SDK/vsphere-ws/docs/ReferenceGuide/vim.Folder.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use powerCLI to create a VM/Template folder

https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6bd6daa3-08a8-4660-9159-23265b9d6c00/4d533cf0-f009-4fa0-8679-8d505fbe846b/doc/New-Folder.html